# Scrapy - Parsing Data from Multiple Pages

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape a website, extract data from various pages, and then store that scraped data into a list. I am trying to scrape a name, url, and location from the first page, then from that scraped url traverse to that page and scrape the DOCTYPE from that page. See below for the code that I have crafted, I have been following this **[documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)** closely but I am getting weird results.

If I don't try to use a second method within my ExampleSpider I get back a list of 3000+ results, which is exactly what I want...minus that essential second piece of data. When I try to include this method all I get back are the starting URL's (ie. http://www.example.com, http://www.example1.com, etc.).

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from example.items import Item
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["list of about 15 different websites (ie. 'http://example.com', 'http://example1.com')"]

    # #Working method to scrape all of the data I need (except DOCTYPE from second page)
    # def parse(self, response):
    #   for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr'):
    #     item = Item()
    #     item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
    #     item['website'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
    #     item['location'] = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
    #     yield item


    def parse(self, response):
      for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr'):
        item = PharmaItem()
        item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
        item['website'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
        item['location'] = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
        #Setting up a new request to pass to the get_DT method, also passing along the 'item' class meta data

        #converting website from list item to string
        website = ''.join(item['website'])
        request = scrapy.Request(website, callback=self.get_DT)
        request.meta['item'] = item

        return request

    #Get DOCTYPE from each page
    def get_DT(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['website'] = response.url
        dtype  = re.search("<!\s*doctype\s*(.*?)>", response.body, re.IGNORECASE)
        item['DOCTYPE'] = dtype

        yield item
```

**UPDATE** These are the two final functions that I used that worked. I took offwhitelotus's suggestion and tried it but this didn't work as it kept returning the parent DOCTYPE and not the traversed page DOCTYPE.

```
  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr'):
      item = PharmaItem()
      item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
      website = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]
      item['location'] = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()

      # Setting up a new request to pass to the get_DT method, also passing along the 'item' class meta data
      request = scrapy.Request(website, callback=self.get_DT)
      request.meta['item'] = item
      yield request

  #Takes in the websites that were crawled from previous method and finds DOCTYPES
  def get_DT(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['DOCTYPE'] = response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
    item['website'] = response.url

    yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a loop, but calling `return` in it. It will prevent the loop from going through all the links. Use `yield` instead, in the `parse()` function.

Other than that, I don't get this part:

```
#converting website from list item to string
website = ''.join(item['website'])
```

That just seems wrong. If there are multiple web URL's there, this will result in a very bad and invalid URL. And if there is just one of them, then you should have collect it by getting the first and only list element (note the `[0]` at the end):

```
item['website'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are setting the `item['website']` in the `parse()` function, since you are going to override it in the `get_DT` function anyway. You should just use a temporary variable, like so:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr'):
    item = PharmaItem()
    item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
    item['location'] = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
    website = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
    request = scrapy.Request(website, callback=self.get_DT)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request
```

Comment: My allowed_urls was restricting my spider from scraping those other pages :o I didn't realize this was an optional attribute, as soon as I deleted this attribute and took your suggestions it's working great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lawrence about fixing that line.

Also, I'm not sure why you have that callback function. You can get the doctype easily with:

```
import requests
html = requests.get('http://something.com').content
dtype = re.search("<!\s*doctype\s*(.*?)>", html, re.IGNORECASE)
```

I've never used `scrapy.Requests`, so I just used good old `requests` here.

Comment: This works, sure. But when working with Scrapy, its best to leave all requests to be handled by Scrapy, as it uses Twisted and asynchronous requests under the hood. Best to not step over its toes, even though this probably has no real impact for simple examples, it could for extensive and massive scraping applications. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but what I kept getting back for each scraped ExampleItem was the doctype of the parent page (in this case www.example.com). All of the doctypes were the same. See above for my updated code that I managed to get to work.